# A continuum of fixed points?

Tags: differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be $C^\infty$. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a fixed point of $F$.  My question is as follows, how would I go about figuring out if $(x_0,y_0)$ is an isolated fixed point or if there are a continuum of fixed points near by. To provide a rigorous definition of the latter I would say something along the following (but am not wedded to this definition)

> There exists $\epsilon>0$ and $h(z)$ which is continuous in $z$ and
> $h(z)=0$ such that for all $z$ with $|z|<\epsilon$ we have
> $F(x_0+z,y_0+h(z))=(x_0+z,y_0+h(z))$

Essentially, when looking at the displacement map $F(x)-x$, I would like to be able to distinguish between figure 3.1 and the first zero in 3.2 on page 805 of this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1573438282020128), or found here:

[image: Image of Figure from linked paper]

I know that it is necessary that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a critical point of $F(x)-x$ but that does not distinguish between the two cases Im interested in. Is there a quick/straight forward way to check?

Comment: Could you please reproduce the "figure 3.1 and 3.2 on page 805 of the following paper"? They are behind a paywall.

Comment: I would start by deciding if $DF(x_0,y_0)$ has real eigenvalues.

Comment: About your definition: 1) You probably mean "$h(0)=0$" instead of "$h(z)=0$". 2) The null function $h(z)=0$ is solution to the definition, so there should be some condition to prevent this. For example: $\exists \epsilon > 0, \exists h: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ continuous, $h(1/2)=(x_0,y_0)$, $\lVert h(0)-(x_0,y_0) \rVert = \epsilon = \lVert h(1)-(x_0,y_0) \rVert$. But there are other options than a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pose $G(x,y)=F(x,y)-(x,y)$. Then fixed points of $F$ are zeroes of $G$.

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a zero of $G$ and $G$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$-differentiable around $(x_0,y_0)$, then posing $(h,k)=(x-x_0,y-y_0)$, $G(x,y)$ is locally equivalent to:
$\begin{cases}
G_x(x,y) = \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x} h + \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y} k \\
G_y(x,y) = \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial x} h + \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial y} k 
\end{cases}$

This system admits only $(h,k)=(0,0)$ as zero for $G(x,y)$, except if
$\frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial y} - \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial x} = 0$

So a sufficient condition to have an isolated zero for $G$ on $(x_0,y_0)$ is
$\frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial y} - \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial x} \ne 0$.

Coming back to $F$, a sufficient condition for $(x_0,y_0)$ to be an isolated fixed point is
$(\frac {\partial F_x} {\partial x} - 1) (\frac {\partial F_y} {\partial y} - 1) - \frac {\partial F_x} {\partial y} \frac {\partial F_y} {\partial x} \ne 0$
(with all partials computed on $(x_0,y_0)$).

OP remarked in comments that this is not sufficient to distinguish between cases 3.1 and 3.2, which was the main request. So we have to go one level deeper in partial derivatives. For simplification we'll use now vectors, with $DG_x = (\frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x}, \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y})$, and $v=(h,k)$.

We are still on the point $(x_0,y_0)$ which is a zero of $G$. At order 2, we get:
$\begin{cases}
G_x(x,y) = DG_x v + \frac 1 2 v^T HG_x v \\
G_y(x,y) = DG_y v + \frac 1 2 v^T HG_y v 
\end{cases}$
where $H$ is the Hessian operator, i.e.
$HG_x = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac {\partial^2 G_x} {\partial x^2} \frac {\partial^2 G_x} {\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac {\partial^2 G_x} {\partial y \partial x} \frac {\partial^2 G_x} {\partial y^2}
\end{pmatrix}$

The condition $\frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial y} - \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial x} = 0$, which is verified by both 3.1 and 3.2 cases, means that matrix $DG$ has a null determinant, where
$DG=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac {\partial G_x} {\partial x} \frac {\partial G_x} {\partial y} \\
\frac {\partial G_y} {\partial x} \frac {\partial G_y} {\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}$

If $|DG|=0$, $DG$'s kernel can have dimension 1 or 2. It is among this kernel that we want to know the effect of $HG$:

- If $\ker(DG) = \{0\}$, the zero of $G$ on $(x_0,y_0)$ is isolated.
- If $\ker(DG) \ne \{0\}$ and $\forall v \ne 0 \in \ker(DG), v^T HG_x v \ne 0$ or $v^T HG_y v \ne 0$, we are in case 3.2.
- If $\exists v \ne 0 \in \ker(DG), v^T HG_x v = v^T HG_y v = 0$, we may be in case 3.1 or 3.2.

To continue exploring this last case, we might use order-3 partial derivatives. However, whatever the order of derivatives we use, there are cases that cannot be settled, such as (for $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions, but it can be adapted) $\exp(-\frac 1 {x^2})$ whose derivatives on $0$ are all null.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. First, I think it should be $(\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}-1)(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}-1)$, ie $det[DF-I]\neq 0$. However, what about $F_x(x,y)=\ln(x)+1$ and $F_y(x,y)=\ln(y)+1$. This has a unique fixed point at $(1,1)$ and $det[DF-I]=0$. Seemingly violating your condition. I dont think your system rules out the case of $G(x_0,y_0)=0$ while also being a unique local maximum for example, as in figure 3.2.

Comment: @Julieawl9 Yes, sorry for the blunder, it is $(\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}-1)(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}-1)$, I'll correct it. The fact that there is an example violating my condition is not a problem: this is a _sufficient_ condition, not a _necessary_ one. We could then use second-order partial derivatives too, but that would still not be a necessary and sufficient condition. It is impossible to have a NSC based on derivatives alone, because of functions such as $\exp(-\frac 1 {x^2})$ which have all null derivatives (on $0$).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. My concern is what you have produced is exactly the condition of critical point of $F-x$, which is what I have in my initial question. This is not sufficient for an isolated fixed point, this is sufficient for a non-regular fixed point. When I mean non-regular I mean 3.1 or 3.2. For example, if $F$ is the identity map then there are a cont. of FP and all are critical points. My question was how I would tell 3.1 apart from 3.2 and a critical point must be satisfied for both types.

Comment: @Julieawl9 You are right, this is not sufficient to distinguish between cases 3.1 and 3.2. So I have now added one order of differentiation in the answer.